# How to override /usr/local/bin missing from bash profile

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to override a command that currently defaults to the executable in `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`. I thought I could do it by exporting a PATH to ffmpeg installed with homebrew above the one installed in `/usr/local/bin`, but when I edit `~/.bash_profile` I cannot find the exported path `/usr/local/bin`. Yet, when I echo the PATH I see `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/` with the exported paths appended to it. Any idea how I can override commands in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Maybe you have a `~/.profile` which sets it?

Comment: Add an alias like `alias ffmpeg='/what/ever/path/ffmpeg'` to your `~/.bash_profile'`

Comment: great workaround, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. /home/user/.profile and other things actually included from global /etc/profile.d, /etc/bash.bashrc and so on, depending on your distributive. They are primary for your shell.
2. There is no defaults, Linux just searching first occurence of executable in your PATH, so just place directories in correct order in PATH:

> ```
>   Instead of:
>   PATH=$PATH:/mydirectory/bin
>   Use:
>   PATH=/mydirectory/bin:$PATH
> ```